# List of default SystemSoundID

Tags: swift, xcode, soundeffect, system-sounds

I'm trying to implement `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(****))` therefor I need a list of existing IDs for Apples SystemSounds. Searching through various posts I found [this](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) on GitHub. I couldn't find a fitting sound in this list for my purpose. Since this repository wasn't updated since 2013 I'm not sure if its up to date. I would like to know if there is a list of SystemSounds which is more up to date.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the list you have found is not published by Apple.
I do not know if the author researched by themself or just collected them, but that sort of action is considered as a reverse engineering which is inhibited in developer agreement.

***I couldn't find a fitting sound in this list for my purpose.***

You may need to find a sound resource instead of SystemSoundID, and register it and create a SystemSoundID for it using [`AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405240-audioservicescreatesystemsoundid).

***I would like to know if there is a list of SystemSounds which is more up to date.***

The latest list of public SystemSoundID is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405240-audioservicescreatesystemsoundid):

> ### Alert Sound Identifiers
>
> #### Constants
>
> - `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate`
>
>   On the iPhone, use this constant with the 
>     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound
>     function to invoke a brief vibration. On the iPod touch, does nothing.
> - `kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert`
>
>   On the desktop, use this constant with the 
>     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound
>     function to play the alert specified in the Sound preference pane.
> - `kSystemSoundID_FlashScreen`
>
>   On the desktop, use this constant with the 
>     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound
>     function to display a flash of light on the screen.
> - `kUserPreferredAlert`
>
>   Deprecated. Use `kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert` instead.

(Some of them are for macOS only.)

---

Using other SystemSoundIDs, can be considered as using private API.

Some comments from Apple developers in Apple's devforums:

[Does this count as a private API?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/132922#132922)

> It would not be appropriate to use undocumented arbitrary values in APIs, so I would recommend you *not* do that in your submission.

[Haptic feedback for force touch?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/174436#174436)

> For a fixed SystemSoundID value to be considered API, it must have a symbolic constant in the headers.  Passing in other fixed values is not OK.